# Help with a proof of a theorem about convex sets

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm studying the following theorem:

---

***Theorem 1.** Let $C$ be a convex set and let $\textbf{y}$ be a point exterior to the closure of $C$. Then there is a vector $\textbf{a}$ such that $\displaystyle\textbf{a}^T\textbf{y}<\inf_{x\in C}\textbf{a}^T\textbf{y}$.*

*Proof.* Let $$\delta=\inf_{x\in C}|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|>0.$$

There is an $\textbf{x}_0$ on the boundary of $C$ such that $|\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y}|=\delta$. This follows because the continuous function $f(x)=|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|$ achieves its minimum over any closed and bounded set and it is clearly only necessary to consider $\textbf{x}$ in the intersection of the closure of $C$ and the $\color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{\text{sphere of radius }2\delta\text{ centered at }\textbf{y}.}}}$

We shall show that setting $\textbf{a}=\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y}$ satisfies the conditions of the theorem.

Let $x\in C$. For any $\alpha, 0 \le\alpha\le 1$, the point $\color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{\textbf{x}_0+\alpha(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0)\in \overline{C}}}}$ and thus $$|\textbf{x}_0+\alpha(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0)-\textbf{y}|^2\ge|\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y}|^2.$$ Expanding, $$2\alpha(\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y})^T(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0)+\alpha^2|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0|^2\ge 0.$$ Thus, considering this as $\alpha \to 0+$, we obtain $$(\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y})^T(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0)\ge0$$ or, $$\begin{align}
(\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y})^T\textbf{x}\ge(\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y})^T\textbf{x}_0 &= (\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y})^T\textbf{y}+(\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y})^T(\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y})\\
&=(\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y})^T\textbf{y}+\delta^2
\end{align}.$$ Setting $\textbf{a}=\textbf{x}_0-\textbf{y}$ proves the theorem. $\blacksquare$

---

I have highlighted the points I have questions about:

1st rectangle: Why did the author select sphere with radius $2\delta$? isn't sphere of radius $\delta$ enough?

2nd rectangle: I don't understand why $\textbf{x}_0 + \alpha(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0) \in \overline{C}$ for any $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$, because lets say that $\alpha = 1$. Then $\textbf{x}_0 + \alpha(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0)$ becomes $\textbf{x}_0 + \textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0 = \textbf{x} \in C$?!...what did I do wrong :) Can someone clarify my mistake :)

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We need just a tiny bit more than $\delta$, to be sure we're dealing with a nonempty compact set (a priori, before we deduce that a minimum occurs).
2. What we have there is a convex combination of two points in $\bar{C}$. Since $C$ is convex, so is $\bar{C}$, hence closed under convex combinations of elements.

Comment: +1 Thank you @Jonathan Y. (1) I understood, (2) I didn't understand :( Why does $\textbf{x}_0$ and $\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0$ belong to $\overline{C}$? Does $\overline{C}$ and $C$ share the boundary points? :) And when $\alpha = 1$ the the theorem says that $\textbf{x} \in \overline{C}$, but it also said before that $\textbf{x} \in C$ so?...what is going on :D

Comment: Well, the boundary of $C$--which we denote $\partial C$--is a subset of $\bar{C}$ (in fact, $\bar{C}=C\cup\partial C$, so naturally $C\subseteq\bar{C}$ as well), but here we have $x_0+t(x-x_0) = (1-t)x_0 + tx$. This is a convex combination of $x,x_0\in\bar{C}$, as $0\leq t,(1-t)$ and $t+(1-t)=1$.

Comment: +1 Aaa..darmet x) I misunderstood the notation :D Does $\overline{C}$ refer here to closure and NOT complement? :)

Comment: Yes, the closure of $C$ :)